.htaccess for news title
I'd like to open a news link as a direct link, such as:
    index.php/my-news-title-here

but "officially" the page that will be opened will be like
    leggi.php?permalink=my-news-title-here

as I'll load from my DB all the data "where permalink = $_GET['permalink']
I've read a lot of solutions but I'm not able to sort it out... this is my actual .htaccess
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(?:.*/)?(\d+) /leggi.php?permalink=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

but if I put a simple $_GET['permalink'], nothing appears
any helpful suggestions?
I'd like to convert a direct link, such as:
    index.php/my-news-title-here

into
    leggi.php?permalink=my-news-title-here

I've read a lot of solutions but I'm not able to sort it out... this is my actual .htaccess
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(?:.*/)?(\d+) /leggi.php?permalink=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

but if I put a simple $_GET['permalink'], nothing appears

There is nothing in "my-news-title-here" that could be captured by (\d+) which is what you cite with $1. That is why $_GET['permalink'] is empty. \d captures any digit, so \d+ captures any number .

It mighty be that you are looking for something like RewriteRule (?:index\.php/)?([^/]+)$ /leggi.php?permalink=$1 [L,QSA], but that is unclear from your question. Instead of "I'd like to convert" try to say what URL should be requested by a client browser and what internal resource should get called. Use the "edit" button below your question to add that information, do not post it in a comment here.

Hi arkascha, I've updated as per your request :)

Still not really precise, why did you change the wording i suggested? I understand your altered question that "https://example.com/index.php/my-news-title-here" is entered into a browser's address bar, right? And that you want to rewrite such incoming requests internally to leggi.php?permalink=my-news-title-here, right?

By the way: your question had doubled content. The second half still holds the original phrasing. I suggests you remove that, it is irritating and does not offer any additional information. Asking one thing once is enough. Thanks.

Correct arkascha,
basically the link will be "mysite.com/index.php/my-news-title" but internally the request will go into "mysite.com/leggi.php?permalink=-my-news-title"

OK, so my initial comment applies. Do you understand what I pointed out in that comment? About \d not making any sense there?

ok, so it will be:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (?:index.php/)?([^/]+)$ /leggi.php?permalink=$1 [L,QSA]
but even doing that, if I call $_GET['permalink'] I can't see any variable passed

Works as intended: https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=082f0b22-187b-4714-b411-3394f2a87887  If it does not work for you then your situation is different. Most likely some additional rewriting rules you did not tell us about or differences in the file system layout. Only you can say. You will have to add more detailed information to the question.

Make sure the rewriting module is actually loaded and activated inside your http server. Make sure you actually allowed the application of such rules by means of the AllowOverride directive. Are there any relevant entries in your http server's error log file?
